# how to obfuscate the whole package using pyarmor?

Tags: python, obfuscation, pyarmor

I'm trying to obfuscate my python project using pyarmor, when I tried do it using pyarmor web UI, I was getting faied error without details, now I'm trying do it with pyarmor commands, Please al the modules of my project, in the below screen shot

[image]

I'm trying to obfuscate al the model of about image, for that refered this webpage
https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

the below section in that page

```
  Obfuscating Whole Package
Run the following command to obfuscate a package:

pyarmor obfuscate --recursive --output dist/mypkg mykpg/__init__.py
```

could you please help me on how to use it for my case

Comment: What's the question? How do I use pyarmor? [Read the documentation](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#obfuscating-python-scripts), give it a go, and if you run into any problems you can ask a more specific question on here.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis please find my updated query

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the question is I'm afraid. You want to use pyarmor to obfuscate your package - does the documentation not give you enough information? Do you have any error messages when you try the command you copied? What is it that you're trying to achieve with pyarmor?

Comment: in this command how can use my module as entry point

Answer (score 0):

I am answering after 2 years maybe the update version will help other people. To obfuscate the whole python package stored in this structure:

```
myproject
 |--src
    |--mypkg
        |-- {you python files}
```

use the command

```
pyarmor gen -O dist -i src/mypkg
```

this will obfuscate all the python files present in the `pypkg` in the `dist` directory.